# How to remove left/right white space in revolution slider

Tags: css, slider

I'm trying setting up a carousel slider for my website, problem is I've different size of images horizontal and vertical so here i can't fix this white space, please look at this screenshot there are three images and center image has white space in the left and right side.. I'm using revolution slider..[image]

Comment: any piece of code would be nice

Comment: Based on the information you provided, the only thing I can tell is to try margin: 0; padding: 0; On which element? Well, I can't say, because it is only a screenshot!